# Django template filter keeps giving "unsupported operand type"

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-templates, django-template-filters

I keep getting this error with my template filter: 
"unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.date'" I've looked at many other answers dealing with this error but I can't seem to find what's wrong. Any pointers much appreciated.

This is my template filter:

```
@register.filter(name='get_due_date_string')
def get_due_date_string(value):
    delta = value - date.today()

    if delta.days == 0:
        return "Today!"
    elif delta.days < 1:
        return "%s %s ago!" % (abs(delta.days),
            ("day" if abs(delta.days) == 1 else "days"))
    elif delta.days == 1:
        return "Tomorrow"
    elif delta.days > 1:
        return "In %s days" % delta.days
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get delta between `datetime` and `date` object.  You have to extract date from the `datetime` object:

```
delta = value.date() - date.today()
```